# What is the PowerShell equivalent to LINQ's Select?

Tags: powershell

(I know this sounds like a duplicate, but hear me out)

Given the following code, if `Select-Object` where equivalent to LINQ's `Select`, the output should be `@("o", "n", "e")`

```
"one", "two" | %{$_.GetCharArray()} | select -first 1
```

However, since the output is `"o"`, this tells me that `Select-Object` actually acts the same as LINQ's `SelectMany` rather than `Select`.

So many question is: Is there a direct equivalent to `Select` in PowerShell (ie. one that would not merge the collections in the pipeline)

Comment: Not everyone here is familiar with Linq. If you could post example of what you have and what you need, it would greatly increase your chances to get the right answer

Comment: @user978511 - My last sentence pretty much covers it (that is, I'm looking for something that did not merge the two sequences into a single sequence). Roman's answer pretty much covers it, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not about `select` but rather about unrolling arrays obtained by `ToCharArray()` and sent to the pipeline. In order to get expected results using standard `select` we should prevent unrolling. This is typically done by using the unary operator `,` which returns an array with a single item. In our case these items are arrays theselves. They are not unrolled, they are sent to the pipeline as they are. Thus, `select -first 1` selects the first item which is an array with 3 items.

```
"one", "two" | %{, $_.ToCharArray()} | select -first 1
```

This gives 3 items: o, n, e.

Comment: Excellent, just what I was looking for!

Comment: It is good to remember that the LINQ pipeline works differently than PowerShell's pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look ad the work of [Josh Einstein](http://josheinstein.com/blog/index.php/2010/02/linq-for-powershell/)

After load the module you can use a similar .net LINQ sintax in powershell